# gap in timeseries plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, geopandas

I have one-year data and I want to plot their seasonal patterns. SO I just created sub data for each season. but my winter data plot has a gap. It cannot plot three months in sequence.

Here is my data:

[image]

```
winter = pd.concat([countData19_gdf.loc['2019-12-01':'2019-12-31'], countData19_gdf.loc['2019-01-01':'2019-02-28']])
winter= winter.sort_index()
min_count = countData19_gdf['volume'].min()
max_count = countData19_gdf['volume'].max() + 20


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(16,10))


line_width = 2
ax[0,0].plot(winter.resample('d').mean()['volume'].index, winter.resample('d').mean()['volume'], c='blue', lw=line_width);
ax[0,1].plot(countData19_gdf.loc['2019-03-01': '2019-05-31'].resample('d').mean()['volume'].index, countData19_gdf.loc['2019-03-01': '2019-05-31'].resample('d').mean()['volume'] ,c='orange',lw=line_width);
ax[1,0].plot(countData19_gdf.loc['2019-06-01': '2019-08-31'].resample('d').mean()['volume'].index, countData19_gdf.loc['2019-06-01': '2019-08-31'].resample('d').mean()['volume'], c='green', lw=line_width);
ax[1,1].plot(countData19_gdf.loc['2019-09-01': '2019-11-30'].resample('d').mean()['volume'].index, countData19_gdf.loc['2019-09-01': '2019-11-30'].resample('d').mean()['volume'], c='brown', lw=line_width);

ax[0,0].title.set_text('Winter')
ax[0,1].title.set_text('Spring')
ax[1,0].title.set_text('Summer')
ax[1,1].title.set_text('Fall')
for ax in [ax[0,1], ax[1,0], ax[1,1]]:
    # Set minor ticks with day numbers
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.DayLocator(interval=10))
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d'))
    # Set major ticks with month names
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('\n%b'))
plt.savefig('seasonal_global.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The gap in your plot occurs because you are displaying the winter months of two different winters, one that started in 2018 and ended in 2019, and another that started in 2019 and ended in 2020.

You need to subset your data so that it gathers the appropriate months, as the following code does:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

datetime_index = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2020-12-31')

volume = np.random.randint(low=30, high=60, size=datetime_index.shape[0])

data = pd.DataFrame({'volume': volume},
                    index=datetime_index)

winter = data['2019-12':'2020-02']

winter.plot()
```

It plots this:

[image: Volume in winter 2019/20]

If you don't have more than one year's worth of data, then you can fill the gap with the other seasons in light grey, such as the graph below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16,10))
line_width = 2
ax.plot(data['volume'], c='grey', lw=line_width, label='All year')
ax.plot(data[:'2019-02'], c='blue', lw=line_width, label='Winter')
ax.plot(data['2019-12':], c='blue', lw=line_width)
plt.legend()
plt.title('Volume across 2019')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of volume across the year of 2019]

The synthetic data that I've used is more volatile than the real data. You could smooth the time series with a moving average using `rolling()`, to improve the readability of the changes over time.

Comment: I do have only the data for 2019. nothing in my dataset is for 2020

Comment: You could plot all of them on the same axis and colour code the lines by season, so as to avoid the gap.

Comment: Thanks Paulo Schau Guerra. My problem is I am new to python and things take a lot of time. I will try your solution