# How can I change spacing between column in graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am creating a Python script that takes stock data and
generates a graph for that but the problem I am facing is stock data is not available for every Saturday and Sunday so there is some gap in dates. So the graphs looks like this:

[image: stock graph]

As you can see here there is a lot of gap between this. What I want is to remove this gap which means removing unnecessary date which is automatically generated by matplotlib and doesn't have any data making it look like this.
Does anybody know how do to do that I trying everything from 3 days but didn't get any solution for this.

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pytz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json

data = json.loads(open("data.json", "r").read())

local_timezone = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
data = data[:501]
# Extracting relevant data and creating a pandas DataFrame
timestamps = [
    pd.to_datetime(row["Data"][2]["ScalarValue"])
    for row in data
]
values = [float(row["Data"][3]["ScalarValue"]) for row in data]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamps": timestamps, "Values": values})

df.set_index("Timestamps", inplace=True)



plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(df.index, df["Values"], label="Original Data")
plt.xlabel("Timestamps")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.title(
    "Stock Price"
)
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

`data.json` file:

```json
[
  {
    "Data": [
      {
        "ScalarValue": "Nifty Bank"
      },
      {
        "ScalarValue": "price"
      },
      {
        "ScalarValue": "2023-01-20 06:58:00.000000000"
      },
      {
        "ScalarValue": "42644.2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Data": [
      {
        "ScalarValue": "Nifty Bank"
      },
      {
        "ScalarValue": "price"
      },
      {
        "ScalarValue": "2023-01-20 06:59:00.000000000"
      },
      {
        "ScalarValue": "42642.25"
      }
    ]
  },
...
]
```

Comment: What does `ScalarValue` look like when there is no data?

Comment: if `ScalarValue` exists it is guaranteed to have data. it's that there are objects missing in between that means the whole "Data" array is missing. and matplotlib is filling these dates automatically.

Comment: I think you need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70392290/how-to-leave-gaps-in-plot-of-incomplete-timeseries

Comment: If lines are misleading, it means you should plot only points with `plt.plot(..., kind='scatter')`! Lines between points serve no objective purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `weekday()` function from `datetime`. You can try this with your complete `data.json` file.

```
data = json.loads(open("data.json", "r").read())

local_timezone = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
data = data[:501]
# Extracting relevant data and creating a pandas DataFrame
timestamps = [
    pd.to_datetime(row["Data"][2]["ScalarValue"])
    for row in data 
    if pd.to_datetime(row["Data"][2]["ScalarValue"]).weekday() not in [5,6]
]
values = [float(row["Data"][3]["ScalarValue"]) for row in data 
          if pd.to_datetime(row["Data"][2]["ScalarValue"]).weekday() not in [5,6]]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamps": timestamps, "Values": values})

df.set_index("Timestamps", inplace=True)



plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(df.index, df["Values"], label="Original Data")
plt.xlabel("Timestamps")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.title(
    "Stock Price"
)
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The weekday() function returns the day of the week as an integer ranging from `0` to `6`. `0` corresponds to *Monday* and `6` corresponds to *Sunday*.
To skip *Saturday* and *Sunday* in your case, you can avoid considering weekdays `5` and `6`.

Comment: no, in my data.json there is no data for Saturday and Sunday. That's why there is a gap in the graph.